# Not able to copy to clipboard from Popper which is inside Dialogue in material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, copy-paste

Steps to reproduce the bug here: (Try to open in Firefox, I was almost crashed the chrome :P) https://codesandbox.io/s/73z5293391

1. Click on the `OPEN SIMPLE DIALOGUE` button. Now you see a dialogue, Click on the `TOGGLE POPPER` button.
2. Now you see a Popper which has an input box and a COPY button.
3. You need to copy on the text inside the input box in this case `hello`.

So I am not able to copy to clipboard actually. 
First I thought it might be a problem with `Dialogue`. But no. In just a `Dialogue` it works. But not on Popper which pops up from the `Dialogue`(Only for Popper also it works).
Can you help me to copy to clipboard in this situation?

Once again the source code:

```
    import React from "react";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
    import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
    import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
    import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
    import ListItemAvatar from "@material-ui/core/ListItemAvatar";
    import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
    import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
    import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
    import PersonIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Person";
    import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
    import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
    import blue from "@material-ui/core/colors/blue";
    import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
    import Popper from "@material-ui/core/Popper";

    const emails = ["username@gmail.com", "user02@gmail.com"];

    const styles = {
      avatar: {
        backgroundColor: blue[100],
        color: blue[600]
      }
    };

    class SimpleDialog extends React.Component {
      state = {
        anchorEl: null,
        openPopper: false
      };

      handleClose = () => {
        this.props.onClose(this.props.selectedValue);
      };

      handleListItemClick = value => {
        this.props.onClose(value);
      };

      copytoClipBoard = () => {
        this.hello.select();
        try {
          return document.execCommand("copy");
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("Oops, unable to copy");
        }
      };

      handleClick = event => {
        const { currentTarget } = event;
        this.setState(state => ({
          anchorEl: currentTarget,
          openPopper: !state.openPopper
        }));
      };

      render() {
        const { classes, onClose, selectedValue, ...other } = this.props;
        const { anchorEl, openPopper } = this.state;
        const id = openPopper ? "simple-popper" : null;

        return (
          <Dialog
            onClose={this.handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="simple-dialog-title"
            {...other}
          >
            <DialogTitle id="simple-dialog-title">Set backup account</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
              <Button
                aria-describedby={id}
                variant="contained"
                onClick={this.handleClick}
              >
                Toggle Popper
              </Button>

              <Popper
                id={id}
                open={openPopper}
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                style={{ zIndex: 10000 }}
              >
                <input
                  value="hello"
                  readOnly
                  type="text"
                  ref={node => (this.hello = node)}
                />
                <Button onClick={this.copytoClipBoard}> Copy </Button>
              </Popper>
              <List>
                {emails.map(email => (
                  <ListItem
                    button
                    onClick={() => this.handleListItemClick(email)}
                    key={email}
                  >
                    <ListItemAvatar>
                      <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                        <PersonIcon />
                      </Avatar>
                    </ListItemAvatar>
                    <ListItemText primary={email} />
                  </ListItem>
                ))}
                <ListItem
                  button
                  onClick={() => this.handleListItemClick("addAccount")}
                >
                  <ListItemAvatar>
                    <Avatar>
                      <AddIcon />
                    </Avatar>
                  </ListItemAvatar>
                  <ListItemText primary="add account" />
                </ListItem>
              </List>
            </DialogContent>
          </Dialog>
        );
      }
    }

    SimpleDialog.propTypes = {
      classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      onClose: PropTypes.func,
      selectedValue: PropTypes.string
    };

    const SimpleDialogWrapped = withStyles(styles)(SimpleDialog);

    class SimpleDialogDemo extends React.Component {
      state = {
        open: false,
        selectedValue: emails[1]
      };

      handleClickOpen = () => {
        this.setState({
          open: true
        });
      };

      handleClose = value => {
        this.setState({ selectedValue: value, open: false });
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Typography variant="subtitle1">
              Selected: {this.state.selectedValue}
            </Typography>
            <br />
            <Button
              variant="outlined"
              color="primary"
              onClick={this.handleClickOpen}
            >
              Open simple dialog
            </Button>
            <SimpleDialogWrapped
              selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue}
              open={this.state.open}
              onClose={this.handleClose}
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default SimpleDialogDemo;
```

Answer (score 2):

@akhila-hegde You can add `disablePortal` to the Popper to solve this. 
Note that problem is not with Copy to clipboard. Problem is that you are not able to select the text in the field (because it is in a Portal).

Here is Sandbox link with disablePortal set to true - https://codesandbox.io/s/lxjwj3p8m9

Comment: Disabling portal is not the solution. Because I removed the Popper, which I want. Rather we do is passing a prop: `disableEnforceFocus` to the Dialogue.